# How to add an index to each option as a value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my HTML snippet

```
<div class="well">
    <h5>Test Subject ID No.:</h5>
    <select id="selDataset" onchange="optionChanged(this.value)"></select>
</div>
```

This is how I appended options

```
const url = "./samples.json";
```

```
var selectDropdown = d3.select("#selDataset")

function addOptions() {
    d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

        data.names.forEach(name => {
            var appendOption = selectDropdown.append("option").text(name)
        })
    })
}

addOptions()
```

I am now trying to add an index to each option as a value, any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean a literal index property?

Comment: I basically want my options to look like this
<option value= 0> 940 <option>
<option value= 1> 941 <option>
etc

Comment: It's been a bit since I've used d3, but does it have a `.html` method that you can just append direct HTML to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 has an [`.attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_attr) method which does what you want.

```
var selectDropdown = d3.select("#selDataset");

function addOptions() {
    d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

        data.names.forEach((name, i) => {
            var appendOption = selectDropdown.append("option").text(name).attr('value', i);
        });
    });
}

addOptions();
```